# What does '%' do?

Tags: python, operators, symbols

I ran this code

`x = 2`

`y = 6`

`print(x%y)`

***Output***

2

What did '%' exactly do?

Comment: Did you know that search engines are now good enough that you can put in something like [`python what is %`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+what+is+%25) and get good answers?

Answer (score 0):

It's the modulo operator, it gives the rest from a division that doesn't give an integer( or 0  if the division gives an integer)

So 10 modulo 4 is 2 since 10-4*2=2